# MySQL Left Join AND OR

Tags: mysql

Three tables in my database:

(1) `orders` (2) `mastersku` (3) `inventory`

Basic logic is `orders` come in, reference the `mastersku` table, and insert new quantity levels from appropriate skus in the `inventory` table.

orders table:

[image]

mastersku table:

[image]

inventory table:

[image]

As you can see on the `mastersku` table, some sku's have multiple skus. My logic is that if a SKU has multiple SKUs, `MultSKU` has a value of `1` (and `AltSKU` is NULL, with the different skus in SKU_1, SKU_2, etc)

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
  Inventory.id,
  Inventory.SKU AS inventory_sku,
  Inventory.Quantity AS inventory_quantity,
    MasterSKU.SKU_1,
    MasterSKU.SKU_2,
    MasterSKU.SKU_3,
    MasterSKU.SKU_4,
    MasterSKU.SKU_5,
    MasterSKU.MultSKU,
    MasterSKU.QtySKU,
    MasterSKU.AltSKU,
    MasterSKU.SKU,
      Orders.Quantity AS sold_quantity,
      Orders.SKU AS sold_sku
FROM Orders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mastersku
    ON Orders.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU
  LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory
    ON MasterSKU.AltSKU = Inventory.SKU
    OR MasterSKU.SKU_1 = Inventory.SKU
GROUP BY Orders.SKU
```

This results in

[image]

Similarly, if I change `OR MasterSKU.SKU_1 = Inventory.SKU` to `OR MasterSKU.SKU_2 = Inventory.SKU`

I get seperate desired results.

[image]

What I need to do, and am having a kicking time trying to get right, is combine the two queries. Something like

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory
ON MasterSKU.AltSKU = Inventory.SKU
OR MasterSKU.SKU_1 = Inventory.SKU
AND OR MasterSKU.SKU_2 = Inventory.SKU
AND OR MasterSKU.SKU_3 = Inventory.SKU
```

(but obviously this is not correct syntax..)

to get a desired result of... (this cheap paint copy+paste)

[image]

I'm working in PHP but this is my first time doing a major project with my own designed MySQL database. Any help please? Here is a little SQLFiddle if it helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4fd2/4

Comment: It probably would be best to get rid of all the `SKU_#` columns, and use a 1-to-many table that lists all the alternate SKUs for a master SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list columns in an `IN` list:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory
ON Inventory.SKU IN (MasterSKU.AltSKU, MasterSKU.SKU_1, MasterSKU.SKU_2, MasterSKU.SKU_3, MasterSKU.SKU_4, MasterSKU.SKU_5)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4fd2/6)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly how I wanted it, and so simple too haha.  Was not aware you could use `IN` this way

Comment: You could also just use a whole bunch of `OR`s: `WHERE Inventory.SKU = AltSKU OR Inventory.SKU = SKU_1 OR Inventory.SKU = SKU_2 ...`

Comment: Yup! Thanks for the alternative as well :)